# How do I create JOOQ DSLContext from reactive MariaDB connection

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jooq, reactive, r2dbc

JOOQ manual states the following:

> Out of the box, all jOOQ provided publishers will block on the
> underlying JDBC connection, but if you provide jOOQ with a
> io.r2dbc.spi.Connection or io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory, then the
> publishers will execute queries in a non-blocking fashion on an R2DBC
> driver.

How do I provide DSLContext with io.r2dbc.spi.Connection or io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory ?

I tried DSL.using() but it does not accept this interface.

Also - can I define the DSLContext with reactive driver through Spring Boot ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I provide DSLContext with io.r2dbc.spi.Connection or io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory ?

At the time of this question, jOOQ 3.14 did not yet support R2DBC. With jOOQ 3.15, you can write this:

```java
DSLContext ctx1 = DSL.using(connection);
DSLContext ctx2 = DSL.using(connectionFactory);
```

Just like with JDBC connections.

> Also - can I define the DSLContext with reactive driver through Spring Boot ?

I suspect that this will be possible once jOOQ 3.15 is released (~ end of Q2 2021, no promises). Until then, just expose a `@Bean` of type `DSLContext` that you build manually from an injected `ConnectionFactory`